# Fetch data from php url to save to local sqlite in react native

Tags: android, ios, json, sqlite, react-native

I want to fetch data from url, example from json.php and then store that to local sqlite in React Native. But I can't find any reference or any problem same like me

I tried to find another database to get data from url and store to local database, but it seems I can't find any case like me.

```
[{
  "username":"****",
  "password":"*****",
  "access":"1",
  "name":"dwi",
  "phone_number":"****",
  "email":"**@***.com",
  "score":null,"status":"0"
 },
 {
  "username":"*****",
  "password":"****",
  "access":"1",
  "name":"******",
  "phone_number":"**********",
  "email":"******@**.com",
  "score":null,
  "status":"0"
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things you need to do -

1) Hit the url and retrieve the data [HTTP GET/ HTTP POST] depending on your api.

2) You need to parse the response.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_http.htm) is an example of using HTTP requests with react-native.

3) Now, after data is parse, you need to write it to your database.

[Here](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#opening-a-database) is an example of handling SQLite with react-native.

Another example of sqlite [here](https://www.djamware.com/post/5caec76380aca754f7a9d1f1/react-native-tutorial-sqlite-offline-androidios-mobile-app).

Now, please read the documentation and try to implement it.

Comment: thank you for the http reference , i can get data the now.. but i prefer use asyncstore (cause the data that i get no to much) , and i have question in another section